# Como enviar uma lista de objetos por bundle?

Tags: java, android

Estou trabalhando com um sistema de abas, uma para cada mês, e uma listagem de aniversário nas respectivas abas.

Meu adapter está da seguinte maneira:

```
FragmentPagerItemAdapter adapter = new FragmentPagerItemAdapter(
                getSupportFragmentManager(), FragmentPagerItems.with(this)
                .add(R.string.mes1, MesFragment.class, bundles.get(1))
                .add(R.string.mes2, MesFragment.class, bundles.get(2))
                .add(R.string.mes3, MesFragment.class, bundles.get(3))
                .add(R.string.mes4, MesFragment.class, bundles.get(4))
                .add(R.string.mes5, MesFragment.class, bundles.get(5))
                .add(R.string.mes6, MesFragment.class, bundles.get(6))
                .add(R.string.mes7, MesFragment.class, bundles.get(7))
                .add(R.string.mes8, MesFragment.class, bundles.get(8))
                .add(R.string.mes9, MesFragment.class, bundles.get(9))
                .add(R.string.mes10, MesFragment.class, bundles.get(10))
                .add(R.string.mes11, MesFragment.class, bundles.get(11))
                .add(R.string.mes12, MesFragment.class, bundles.get(12))
                .create());
```

O fragmento do mês receberá pelo `bundle` a lista completa dos aniversários e o mês em si para poder realizar os filtros antes da exibição.

Configurei uma lista de `bundles` da seguinte maneira:

```
ArrayList<Aniversario> listaAniversariantes = new ArrayList<>()
/* a lista foi declarada assim e por hora já está alimentada estaticamente*/

List<Bundle> bundles = new ArrayList<>(12);
        for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putInt("mes", i);
            b.putSerializable("listaAniversario", listaAniversariantes);
            bundles.add(b);
        }
```

No fragmento do mês estou recuperando as informações do `bundle` da seguinte maneira:

```
int mes = getArguments().getInt("mes");
ArrayList<Aniversario> listaAniversariantes = (ArrayList<Aniversario>) getArguments().getSerializable("listaAniversario");
```

O mês está sendo recuperado corretamente, porém a lista não. Em testes com as informações separadas, quando passo pelo `bundle` só o mês e eu crio a lista dentro do fragmento, tudo funciona normal, quando eu incluo a lista no `bundle`, a aplicação quebra.

Alguém sabe o que pode estar acontecendo?

PS: cogitei usar `Intent`, mas a função `.add("nome da aba", fragmento)` permite a inclusão apenas de um `bundle`.

Answer (score 0):

No episódio de hoje aprendemos que devemos sempre revisar o nosso código!

No adapter passei `.add(R.string.mes1, MesFragment.class, bundles.get(1))` do 1 ao 12 tendo na cabeça os meses, porém o campo é do índice da lista, que vai de 0 a 11, a aplicação estava quebrando pois estava tentando acessar a posição 12 inexistente da lista de `bundle`.

Tópico encerrado e muito obrigado!